# Can I show just a subset of a c# collection in the Visual Studio watch window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, watch-window

I have a list of about 1000 items and I want to debug and examine in the watch window only items in the range 500 to 550. Is this possible in C# in Visual Studio?

I tried `items[500..550]` but I got an error

> Predefined type 'System.Range' is not defined or imported

Comment: Does `myCollection.Skip(500).Take(50)` work? (with `using System.Linq;` in the context)

Comment: Parital credit :-) It does give me just those items, but now they're numbered 0 to 50. I could still do with seeing the original indexes if at all possible.
(If I don't get an answer with the indexes I'm looking for in the next day or so, give me yours as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer thanks)

Comment: Not used Linq for a while but perhaps you could zip Flydog57's answer with a range (500,500+50)?

Comment: You could format your own display; `.Select( (obj, index) => $"{index} - {obj}").Skip(500).Take(50)`

Comment: Unfortunately `items.Skip(500).Take(50).Zip(Enumerable.Range(500, 550), (first, second) => first + " " + second)` just gives me a collection of strings. I need to be able to drill into the items.